# Update for Android Studio from 2.0 preview 4 to 2.0 increases apk size

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.0, android-gradle-2.0

Recently I have updated Android Studio from 2.0 preview to 2.0 stable version. I realised that after this update my app's release apk size changed from 6MB to 14MB.
Anyone have any idea why this is happening and what is the solution to reduce apk size?

Comment: It should not happen. Do you use vector drawbles? Did you turn off proguard?

Comment: No, I m not using vector drawables also proguard is on.

Comment: I have filed an issue for it, here is the link
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=208328